# FileProperties from Azure SDK for Python

Tags: azure-sdk-python, azure-data-lake-gen2

Has any of you worked with `FileProperties`? I am trying to find an information about this class. I want to use the method `get_file_client(file_path)` from [SDK](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.0.0b7/azure.storage.filedatalake.html#azure.storage.filedatalake.FileSystemClient.get_file_client) and pass the path to the file instead of the file name, but the SDK's documentation doesn't reference this class and google doesn't help neither. I would appriciate if anyone could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it is better to use the [DataLakeFileClient Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python-preview)